# windows 8 minor version returning 0 instead of 2

Tags: windows-8, windows-installer, custom-action, windowsversion

I have code in C++ that has the purpose of finding the Windows version:

```
OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;
BOOL bOsVersionInfoEx;

int iRet = OS_UNKNOWN;

ZeroMemory ( & osvi, sizeof ( OSVERSIONINFOEX ) );
osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof ( OSVERSIONINFOEX );

if ( !( bOsVersionInfoEx = GetVersionEx ( ( OSVERSIONINFO * ) & osvi ) ) )
{
    osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof ( OSVERSIONINFO );
    if ( ! GetVersionEx ( ( OSVERSIONINFO * ) & osvi ) )
        return OS_UNKNOWN;      
}
//the rest is irrelevant ...
```

iRet will return an internal enum value identifying the Windows version. It will be ajusted according to the values returned in osvi.dwPlatformId, osvi.dwMajorVersion and osvi.dwMinorVersion.

According to MSDN, for Windows 8 the value of MajorVersion is 6 and the value for MinorVersion is 2.

I have this code compiled in a dll and the code actually works if I call the DLL from a test EXE program.

But if I call THE SAME CODE FROM THE SAME DLL from within a Custom Action within a windows installer package (MSI), GetVersionEx() returns 0 for the MinorVersion field.

Did anybody else experience this bug?
Does anybody know how to work around it?

Comment: You're probably running in compatibility mode.

Comment: True. I ran gpedit.msc and disabled Aplication Compatibility Engine and Program Compatibility Assistant. It started to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Windows Installer lies about the version by default when using GetVersion(Ex) on Windows 7+. The answer is always Vista SP0. You can use the VersionNT MSI value instead.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2009/05/06/why-custom-actions-get-a-windows-vista-version-lie-on-windows-7.aspx